# Can the integral value of ${\int}_{0}^{t} \frac{{x^2} exp(x)}{(exp(x)-1)^2} dx$ for t>0 be obtained analytically?

Tags: calculus, integration

In the process of solving the exercise on the qualitative discussion
of the specific heat of a one-dimensional lattice,
I need to consider the integral of the following f(x).

$$f(x)= \frac{{x^2} \exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-1)^2}  \tag{1-1}$$

The problem I present to you is as follows;

- (1) Can the following integral value be obtained analytically for $t>0$?
  $$F(t):= {\int}_{0}^{t} \frac{{x^2} \exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-1)^2}  dx \tag{1-2}$$
- (2) If the above is not possible, can the limit of $t\to\infty$ be found analytically? In other words, please calculate the following limit values.
  $$\lim_{t \to \infty}F(t) \tag{1-3}$$
- (3) If none of the above is possible, is it possible to approximate "this integral is almost independent of t when t is sufficiently large"? ($F(t)$ can be regarded as a constant)?

As for (3), I plotted a graph of f(x) and found that,
$\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=1$, and
the $f(x)$ rapidly approaches $0$ when $x$ becomes large.

[image: 1]
Fig.A graph showing $F(t)$ from 0 to 15.

Comment: hint: $F(\infty)= {\int}_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{x^2} \exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-1)^2}  dx=-\frac{d}{ds}({\int}_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{x}}{(\exp(sx)-1)}  dx)|_{s=1}=-\frac{d}{ds}(\frac{1}{s^2}{\int}_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{x}}{(\exp(x)-1)}  dx)|_{s=1}=2\zeta(2)\Gamma(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav  Thanks for the comment. Why can this improper integral　be the multiplication of the zeta and gamma functions?

Comment: I follows from $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{\exp(x)-1} dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}\exp(-x)}{1-\exp(-x)} dx$ $=\int_{0}^{\infty} {x^{n-1}\exp(-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\exp(-xk)} dx$ (sum of geometric progression) $=$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} {x^{n-1}\exp(-kx)dx$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{-n}\int_{0}^{\infty} \{x^{n-1}\exp(-x)dx=\zeta(n)\Gamma(n)$

Comment: The sources of the zeta and gamma functions have been clarified. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad if this helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using integration by parts only
$$\int_0^t \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} \, {\rm d}x = -\frac{t^2}{e^t-1} + \underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{2x}{e^x-1} \, {\rm d}x}_{=2\zeta(2)} - \int_t^\infty \frac{2x}{e^x-1} \, {\rm d}x \\
=-\frac{t^2}{e^t-1}  + \frac{\pi^2}{3} + 2t \log(1-e^{-t}) + 2 \underbrace{\int_t^\infty \log(1-e^{-x}) \, {\rm d}x}_{-{\rm Li}_2(e^{-t})} \\
= \frac{\pi^2}{3} - e^{-t} \left( t^2 + 2t + 2 \right) + {\cal O}\left(t^2 e^{-2t}\right)$$
where ${\rm Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose your answer as the best answer because it was clear which term of the integral is what function.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  (k+1) x^2 e^{-x} e^{-kx} dx.$$
Use the series for $(1-z)^2=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)z^k, |z|<1.$
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^2 e^{-(k+1)x} dx$$
$$I=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{ k+1}{(k+1)^3}=2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}=2 \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\log(u)$ to make
$$I=\int\frac{e^x x^2}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}dx=\int\frac{\log ^2(u)}{(u-1)^2}\,du=\int\frac{\log ^2(v+1)}{v^2}\,dv$$Back to $x$
$$I=\int\frac{e^x x^2}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}dx=2 \text{Li}_2\left(e^x\right)+x \left(\frac{e^x x}{1-e^x}+2 \log
   \left(1-e^x\right)\right)$$
$$J=\int_0^t\frac{e^x x^2}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}dx=2 \text{Li}_2\left(e^t\right)+t \left(2 \log \left(1-e^t\right)-\frac{e^t
   t}{e^t-1}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$$

$J$ tends very fast to $\frac {\pi^2}{3}$. Solving for $t$ such that $J(t)=k\frac{\pi^2}{3}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & t_k \\
 0.9000 & 4.59526 \\
 0.9900 & 7.77037 \\
 0.9990 & 10.6318 \\
 0.9999 & 13.3521
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Li is this function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by parts with $u = x^2$ and $dv = \frac{e^x \: dx}{(e^x - 1)^2}$. Then $$\int_0^t \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x - 1)^2} \: dx = \frac{x^2}{1 - e^x} \biggr|_0^t + \int_0^t \frac{2x}{e^x - 1} \: dx$$
The first term goes to zero as t approaches infinity. The second denominator can be replaced by its Maclaurin series:
$$\int_0^t \frac{2x}{e^x - 1} \: dx = \int_0^t \frac{2x}{x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + \ldots} \: dx \leq \int_0^t \frac{2}{1 + x/2 + x^2/6} \: dx$$
The antiderivative of the last integral is $$\frac{24}{\sqrt{15}} \arctan \left( \frac{2x + 3}{\sqrt{15}} \right)$$ This converges as $x$ approaches infinity.
To four decimal places: $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x - 1)^2} \: dx \approx 3.2899$$

Comment: Your idea is a wonderful approximation to prevent the occurrence of special functions such as the zeta function.　Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you too! Have a great day.